# HPQC OTA Client Java API - Get Testcase History

Tags: java, ota, hp-quality-center, com4j

I'm using `ota` client java api to retrieve the test case details.

Can someone please explain how to get history record of each testcases from `hpqc` using `OTA` client for Java API. (using `IHistoryRecord` Interface).

Comment: OTA is basically written in .net, if you use vb/c# .net that would help you to write your code efficiently.

Comment: Can we get some more background over the problem. I have full experience working over OTAClient and communicating from java/.net. If you provide more details, it will help me in understanding issue.

Comment: Below are the snippets, Im getting the testcase info:
List<TestCase> testCaselist;
ITestFactory testFactory = (ITestFactory) conn.testFactory().queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
ITDFilter2 filter = testFactory.filter().queryInterface(ITDFilter2.class);
if (filterSubject != null && !filterSubject.equals(""))
filter.filter("TS_SUBJECT", filterSubject);
IList testIList = filter.newList();
testCaselist = new ArrayList<TestCase>();
for (Com4jObject com4jObject : testIList) {
ITest test = com4jObject.queryInterface(ITest.class);
testCaseId = test.id().toString();
status = test.execStatus();
.....}

Comment: In the UI, There is a 'History' tab, there is a Baselines and Audit Log(FieldName, Old value, New Value....) information available for each test case, the same information I need to get through OTAClient Java API. 
Thanks,